# server variables in functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a function that gets called through a socket.io event.
This function is in another moldule.
I want to make sure that everytime the function gets called the variables in the module are not changed by previous function calls.

I know how to do this in other languages: create a new instance of an object, call the function but i cant seem to get this to work in javascript.

The code looks like this:

socket.io module where the functions gets called

```
// -- all events -- //
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('increase', function (data) {
        var increaser = require('./increase.js');
        increaser.increase();
    });
});
```

increase module, should print 1 everytime, but prints 1..2..3..4....

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

// -- variables -- //
var counter = 0;

module.exports = {
    increase : function () {
        counter += 1;
        console.log(counter);
    }
};
```

I want to know how to do this, because on my server a function gets called that calls a few asyncronous functions and i want to make sure that all variables stay like they are until the whole function is proccesed complete and dont get changed if another client connects and triggers the same event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same exactly like other languages using an instance of `object` as below.

**Method 1**: Simplest function object

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";


module.exports = function() {
   this.counter = 0;
   this.increase = function () {
        this.counter += 1;
        console.log(this.counter);
   };
};
```

**Method 2**: Function with prototype

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";

function Increaser() {

}

Increaser.prototype = {
   counter: 0,
   increase: function () {
        this.counter += 1;
        console.log(this.counter);
   };
};

module.exports = Increaser;
```

And at your `socket.io`,

```
// -- all events -- //
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('user connected');

    socket.on('increase', function (data) {
        var Increaser = require('./increase.js');
        var increaser = new Increaser();
        //  Also you can use as below in one line
        // var increaser = new require('./increase.js')();
        increaser.increase();
    });
});
```

Comment: and now you can get rid of `var counter = 0`

Comment: Yes right @JoseHermosillaRodrigo. corrected now :-)

Comment: @Aruna so i should export every variable the function uses with this.variable in the export function ?

Comment: @Vujukas Yes, instead of a variable, you can use with `this`. Or you can use the same with `prototype` as I mentioned in `method 2` above. Still you should use the property with `this` inside the `increase` method.

Comment: Thank you that really helped

Comment: @Vujukas Can you accept the answer if you are happy with this?

Answer (score 0):

The important concept here is that require() will always return the same object, not a new version each time.

So `var increaser = require('./increase.js');` inside a callback is an anti-pattern.
If you want a new object each time, consider making increase.js return a function which returns your increaser module. Then `var counter` will not be global.